# Making the image not centering when clicked upon

Tags: java, swing

I've got another problem in Swing. I have written a program that prints out images which are movable and when you click on one it will be painted in the front of the other images. 
Although I have a problem that when I want to move an image, if I for example click and drag on the image in a corner, the image jumps so it is centered under the mouse.

```html
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class Bildvisare extends JFrame{  
  public Bildvisare(){
      JPanel panel = new BildPanel();      
      add(panel);
      setSize(640,460);
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public static void main(String[] arg){
      new Bildvisare();
  }
}
//Ritar ut bilderna i en JPanel o stoppar in dem i en ArrayLista
class BildPanel extends JPanel{
 private ArrayList<Image> Bilder = new ArrayList<Image>();
  Image place = null;
  private int xKoord = 300; private int yKoord = 200;  
 

//Ritar upp alla bilder i ramen
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      for (Image p : Bilder){         
          p.draw(g);            
      }        
  }        
//Lägger till "muslyssnare"
  public BildPanel(){      
      MouseHandler mh = new MouseHandler(this);
      addMouseListener(mh);
      addMouseMotionListener(mh);        
      add();
  }
  
//Lägger till bildens fram och baksida i ArrayListan samt deras koorinater
  public void print(String fram, String bak){
      Bilder.add(new Image(fram,bak,xKoord,yKoord));
  }  
 
//Lägger in bilderna i ArrayListan.
  public void add(){
   print("0.gif","backside.gif"); print("1.gif","backside.gif"); 
   print("2.gif","backside.gif"); print("3.gif","backside.gif");
    print("4.gif","backside.gif"); print("5.gif","backside.gif"); 
    print("6.gif","backside.gif");print("7.gif","backside.gif");       
  }
  
//Finner vilken bild som klickas på
  public Image find(int a, int b){        
      for (Image p : Bilder){
          if (p.imageCheck(a, b)){
              place = p;
              }
       }
//      System.out.println(place);
      return place;
  }
  
//Flippar bilden
  public void flip(Image img){
      toFront(img);
      img.flipHelp();
      repaint();
  }
//Gör att den bild man klickat på hamnar "längst fram".
  public void toFront(Image img){
      Bilder.remove(img);
      Bilder.add(img);
  }
  
//Flyttar bilden som klickats på och ritar om ramen med alla bilder.
  public void move(Image img, int x0, int y0){
      toFront(img);
      img.moveHelp(x0,y0);
      repaint();
  }
}

class Image{
private ImageIcon front,backside,inView;
private int x0,y0,bredd,höjd;


public Image(String img_front, String img_back,int x1, int y1){
  backside = new ImageIcon(img_back);
    front = new ImageIcon(img_front);
    inView=front;
    x0=x1;
    y0=y1;
    getSize();      
}

//Draw the image
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(inView.getImage(), x0-bredd/2, y0-höjd/2, null);
}

//Flip the image/icon
public void flipHelp(){
    if (inView==front){
        inView=backside;
    }
    else{
        inView=front;
    }
    getSize();
}

//Get the size of each image/icon
public void getSize(){
    bredd = inView.getIconWidth();
    höjd = inView.getIconHeight();
}

//Move the picture
public void moveHelp(int x1, int y1){
    x0=x1;
    y0=y1;

}

//Check if point is in a certain image
public boolean imageCheck(int x1,int y1){
   return (Math.abs(x1-x0)<(1+bredd)/2&&Math.abs(y1-y0)<(1+höjd)/2); 
  }
}

class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter{
    BildPanel BildPanel;
    Image place = null;
    private int xKoord; private int yKoord;
    
    //Konstruktor för att kunna vända på bilden i mouseClicked()
    public MouseHandler(BildPanel p){
        BildPanel = p;
    }
    
  //Det som händer då en bild trycks på.
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int xKoord = e.getX(); int yKoord = e.getY();       
        place = BildPanel.find(xKoord, yKoord);       
    }
    
//Det som händer då en bild klickas på.
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        int xKoord = e.getX(); int yKoord = e.getY();        
        Image p = BildPanel.find(xKoord, yKoord);
        if (p!=null){
            BildPanel.flip(p);
        }
    }
        
//Det som händer då man "drar" en bild
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        int xKoord = e.getX();
        int yKoord = e.getY();        
        if (place!=null){
            BildPanel.move(place, xKoord, yKoord);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't use the "code snippet" tags when posting code. That is for JavaScript only. Use the "{}" button instead.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163298/dragging-image-using-mousedrag-method/33163542#33163542) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915214/how-can-i-drag-images-with-the-mouse-cursor-in-java-gui/27915358#27915358)

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic for dragging a component around a panel is as follows:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

I would assume the logic is the same for dragging an image. I'll let you compare this working code with your current code to see what is different.